# libgdx characters keeps stop working problem

Tags: libgdx, 2d

I'm new here. I added background first its seems okay. Than i added character now app keeps stop working. Bird.png got problem.
http://prntscr.com/me8v2y

Btw there is error section: http://prntscr.com/me90al

```
public class FlyingSmurfs extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;
Texture background;
Texture bird;

@Override
public void create () {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("background.png");
    background = new Texture("bird.png");


}

@Override
public void render () {

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(bird,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10 , Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8);





    batch.end();
```

Comment: Btw there is error section: http://prntscr.com/me90al

Comment: You forgot `batch.end();`

Comment: thanks for answer morchul. But i already got it 
  batch.begin();
  batch.draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
  batch.draw(bird,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10 , Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8);





  batch.end();

Answer (score 2):

One of your `Texture`s is NULL.

You have two `Texture` objects , `background` and `bird`.

I'm guessing:

```
background = new Texture("background.png");
background = new Texture("bird.png");
```

Should be:

```
background = new Texture("background.png");
bird = new Texture("bird.png");
```

Am I right?